# Is there any API that tells whether an Android device is dual-core or not?

Tags: android

I am doing dual core optimization by multi-threading, and it works like this:
If the device has dual-core processor, two threads are created to do the computation, and if the device has only one-core processor, only one thread is created to do the computation.

My question is: how does my program know whether a device is dual-core or not?
I just want to have one program that can run on both dual-core and one-core devices, so it has to be able to know that information.

code like this:

```
    if( xxx_API_is_device_dual_core() )  // Inside if() is the expected API
    {
     saveThread = new SaveThread[2];
    }
    else
    {
    saveThread = new SaveThread[1];
    }
```

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [Runtime.availableProcessors()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors%28%29) fails to report correctly on the 2-core device?

Comment: wow, this API seems to be what I need! I'll check it in a minute and let you whether it works.

Comment: Runtime.availableProcessors() returns 2 for dual-core device and it's exactly what I have expected. Thank you Denis!

Answer (score 3):

The Runtime.availableProcessors() doesn't seem to work correctly for all Android devices (for example, it only returns "1" on my dual-core Galaxy S II). There may be some confusion between physical CPUs, and virtual CPUs, aka Cores.

The most reliable method I've found is [described in this forum post](http://makingmoneywithandroid.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=298&pid=1663#pid1663). Basically, you have to count the virtual CPU devices in /sys/devices/system/cpu/. This will work with dual-core and quad-core devices with no modifications.

I've tested this method on my Galaxy S II (2 cores) and Asus Transformer Prime (4 cores) and it reports correctly. Here's some sample code (taken from [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10377934/663469)):

```
/**
 * Gets the number of cores available in this device, across all processors.
 * Requires: Ability to peruse the filesystem at "/sys/devices/system/cpu"
 * @return The number of cores, or 1 if failed to get result
 */
private int getNumCores() {
    //Private Class to display only CPU devices in the directory listing
    class CpuFilter implements FileFilter {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            //Check if filename is "cpu", followed by a single digit number
            if(Pattern.matches("cpu[0-9]", pathname.getName())) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }      
    }

    try {
        //Get directory containing CPU info
        File dir = new File("/sys/devices/system/cpu/");
        //Filter to only list the devices we care about
        File[] files = dir.listFiles(new CpuFilter());
        //Return the number of cores (virtual CPU devices)
        return files.length;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //Default to return 1 core
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would place `Runtime.availableProcessors()` as default return value.