# availableProcessors() returns 1 for dualcore phones

Tags: java, android, performance, processors

I recently bought a Moto Atrix 2 mobile. When I tried to look at the processor specs in the phone,
Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() returned 1.
/proc/cpuinfo too had information about just processor 0.

Out of curiosity I checked the same in my friend's Samsung Galaxy S2, which is again a dual core phone. This too showed that no. of cores is 1.

I checked the same in my Moto xoom tablet which is again dual core. This time availableProcessors() returned 2 and cpuinfo also had both processor 0 and processor 1 details.

I am confused. Why some devices carry different information? Can someone explain this anomaly?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` only returns the number of online processors, so it will return 1 when the second core is sleeping.  This is done in order to preserve power during less resource-intensive tasks.

To see all available cores, look at /sys/devices/system/cpu/

Comment: I thought so. But why is that /proc/cpuinfo file too seems to be missing info on the 2nd core?  Also, is there a way to turn on the other core and then check this using the same java method?

Comment: /proc/cpuinfo only shows the online cores.  To see all available cores, look at /sys/devices/system/cpu/.  And unfortunately, no, you can't turn on the second core via your app.

Comment: @lrAndroid Not sure about Runtime.availableProcessors(), I think you need to invoke the class like this, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(). Otherwise a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the number of cores on Android (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10377934/878126)) :

```
public static int getCoresCount()
    {
    class CpuFilter implements FileFilter
      {
      @Override
      public boolean accept(final File pathname)
        {
        if(Pattern.matches("cpu[0-9]+",pathname.getName()))
          return true;
        return false;
        }
      }
    try
      {
      final File dir=new File("/sys/devices/system/cpu/");
      final File[] files=dir.listFiles(new CpuFilter());
      return files.length;
      }
    catch(final Exception e)
      {
      return Math.max(1,Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
      }
    }
```