# Clojure core.async, any way to control number of threads in that (go...) thread pool?

Tags: multithreading, clojure, cpu-usage, core.async

By default (go..) will use [**twice the number of cores + 42**](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async/impl/exec/threadpool.clj)  threads for the thread pool. Is there any way I can set the number of threads, or number of CPUs that the code can use, through setting an environment variable or sth?

On linux machine I can set number of CPU using [taskset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273682/java-cores-available-to-the-jvm), e.g. 
`taskset -c 0,1 my_Java_or_Clojure_program`, although taskset seems not effective on the number returned by `(->   (java.lang.Runtime/getRuntime)  .availableProcessors)`.

Comment: Where in core.async's code does it specify that "2+ number of cores" will be used? I did some looking but did not find it.

Comment: @David from here http://martintrojer.github.io/clojure/2013/07/07/coreasync-and-blocking-io/

Comment: @David From the source code, it looks like twice number of processors plus 42 , https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async/impl/exec/threadpool.clj

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the current Clojure version of core.async, the thread pool executor is located in the `clojure.core.async.impl.dispatch` namespace. You can alter the `executor` var and supply a custom thread pool `ExecutorService`.

```
(ns sandbox
  (:require [clojure.core.async.impl.concurrent :as conc]
            [clojure.core.async.impl.exec.threadpool :as tp]
            [clojure.core.async :as async]))

(defonce my-executor
  (java.util.concurrent.Executors/newFixedThreadPool
   1
   (conc/counted-thread-factory "my-async-dispatch-%d" true)))

(alter-var-root #'clojure.core.async.impl.dispatch/executor
                (constantly (delay (tp/thread-pool-executor my-executor))))

(async/go
 (println 
  (Thread/currentThread))) ;=> #<Thread Thread[my-async-dispatch-1,5,main]>
```

**Note:** Core.async is still in alpha, so, hopefully, this will change in the future.

Comment: I'd just add that this work if and only if you alter the var before core.async calls the creation function, so this should be required quite early in your program

Answer (score 19):

The current accepted answer was valid up to [this commit](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/commit/a690c4f3b7bf9ae9e7bdc899c030955d5933042d#diff-2193dd8597437d6454bb74edd2f15e00) so basically now you have two cases:

- If you want to just change the max number of threads in the pool, you pass the number as Java property [`clojure.core.async.pool-size`](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/43139e44b04dd09bb5faa555ea8ebd2ca09e25ce/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async/impl/exec/threadpool.clj#L20) (it defaults to 8)
- If you want to replace the `ExecutorService`, you use the same trick of `alter-var-root` but targeting the new implementation (there is a protocol to implement):

  ```
   (ns your-app.threadpool
     (:require [clojure.core.async.impl.protocols :as protocols]
               [clojure.core.async.impl.concurrent :as conc]
               [clojure.core.async.impl.exec.threadpool :as tp])
     (:import java.util.concurrent.Executors))

   (defonce my-executor
     (let [executor-svc (Executors/newFixedThreadPool
                         1
                         (conc/counted-thread-factory "async-dispatch-%d" true))]
       (reify protocols/Executor
          (protocols/exec [this r]
            (.execute executor-svc ^Runnable r)))))

   (alter-var-root #'clojure.core.async.impl.dispatch/executor
                   (constantly (delay my-executor)))
  ```