# How get average CPU usage in Android?

Tags: android, performance, cpu, cpu-usage

I want to get the average CPU usage in Android per 100ms or 500ms. I have tried to use `top` and `dumpsys cpuinfo`, but neither of them tell me the average usage or the timestamp. So how can I get the average usage? 
I notice that there is some CPU usage information in `/proc/stat`, can I calculate average CPU usage using `/proc/stat`?

Comment: You can see it in pre-launch report if you have already uploaded your app on google play developer console.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the solution by Krypton, and got wrong numbers (about 22% while getting about 48 via adb shell top). 
So maybe the answer is not running ok on android 7, or there is some bug.

I found a working solution at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405403/android-cpu-cores-reported-in-proc-stat) ,and [code](https://github.com/souch/AndroidCPU/blob/master/app/src/main/java/souch/androidcpu/CpuInfo.java) provided by Souch is already doing the job for us. Just use his CpuInfo class to get the average load each time you need it.