# how many cores are in android devices ? and how many threads i can use for best performance?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

how many cores in android devices although there are allot of manufacturers and how many threads could i use to maximize my performance, In contrast of using only the main thread ?

EDIT : :

The number of cores answer is answered by Nambari , but how many threads to use for best performance is not yet aswered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you could follow might be:

First find out number of cores on the device, this [answer might](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119604/how-to-get-the-number-of-cores-of-an-android-device) help you on that, then follow best practices for thread pool (In my opinion coreCount+1, some people might differ on this approach).

Other solutions might exists based on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: ok i will see it but a question .. the core can have 2 threads right ?

Comment: @ahmednader: Yes, that is why I said few people suggest other approaches like coreCount*2, but I feel it depends on processor architecture.