# Get total number of cores from an android device WTHOUT hyperthreading

Tags: android

As mentioned in the title, I'm looking for a way to get the number of cores of an android device, but without the hyperthreated cores that count as two.

I found that function to get the number of cores:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
```

But a comment here [How to get the number of cores of an android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119604/how-to-get-the-number-of-cores-of-an-android-device) points at that it will count hyperthreated cores double.

So how to avoid that?

**Update**

I tried to get it with (thanks to this website: https://myshell.co.uk/blog/2012/07/how-to-determine-the-number-of-physical-cpus-on-linux/)

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu cores" | uniq
```

It works with Emulator, but not with a real device. That is the cpuinfo:

```
Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 33.76
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 3

Hardware    : MT6580M
Revision    : 0000
Serial      : 0000000000000000
```

So there is no line including 'cpu cores'. Is there any other way to get it?

Comment: I think you need to run some linux command for that. I don't think that ANdroid SDK provides such info

Comment: https://myshell.co.uk/blog/2012/07/how-to-determine-the-number-of-physical-cpus-on-linux/ that works, just have to use that in java, but that is easy

Comment: That does not work, because there is no information in proc/cpuinfo. Is there any other way? Will update the question.

Comment: Could it be that there is now hyperthreading for smartphones and the little and big cores cause the "error" in the comment mentioned above?